# How to implement responsive UI with RFID 522 and camera live feed?

Tags: c#, async-await, rfid, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I have the latest windows iot core installed on raspberry pi3B with a USB camera showing the live feed from camera on a connected HDMI display (like the sample at **https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/webcamapp** )

I came across MFRC 522 module, and found an example project at (2nd answer; **[RFID RC522 Raspberry PI 2 Windows IOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284498/rfid-rc522-raspberry-pi-2-windows-iot)**
 )

My questions is how one would go about implementing the RFID card read without interrupting the UI (lets say live camera feed showing on display), taking the example given in (2nd answer; **[RFID RC522 Raspberry PI 2 Windows IOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284498/rfid-rc522-raspberry-pi-2-windows-iot)**
 )

The code is using async await but what is the best way to make it so that only when the MRFC 522 card read occured, the routine will kick in to read the rfid without interrupting the UI.

Like is there a call back method which can be implemented in the example given or is there a feature in windows iot core when a GPIO connected to the mfrc 522 has a new card scan that it fires a function without constantly listening and breaking the UI responsiveness?

I am new to stackoverflow and cant seem to post on that thread. Hoping to get some pointers from here.

Comment: You need to set up different threads one for the video feed, one for the cardreader, and run them synchronously.

Comment: You can put MFRC 522 logic in a [headless app](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/backgroundapplications) and run it with your camera live app(headed app) simultaneously.