# Win10 IOT Raspberry pi c# RFID rc522

Tags: c#, windows-iot-core-10

I'm using a provided code here -> [RFID RC522 Raspberry PI 2 Windows IOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284498/rfid-rc522-raspberry-pi-2-windows-iot)

I'm printing the uid in a textbox but program stops in this step:

```
await mfrc.InitIO();
```

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.System.Threading;
using Windows.Devices.Gpio;
using Mfrc522Lib;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.Spi;



namespace rfid
{ 
   public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

}





public async void InitRC522Async()
{

    var mfrc = new Mfrc522();
    await mfrc.InitIO();

    while (true)
    {
        if (mfrc.IsTagPresent())
        {
            var uid = mfrc.ReadUid();
                textbox_1.Text = uid.ToString();

            mfrc.HaltTag();
        }
    }
}

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InitRC522Async();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Device Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/deviceportal) to change the default controller driver as ***Inbox Driver***.The Direct Memory Mapped Driver is for [lightning providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/lightningproviders). BTW,you need to restart your device after changing the default controller driver setting.

[image]

Comment: After selecting the "Inbox Driver" option item, please click Update Drvier button, and then reboot your device.If it still does not work,please tell me what exception thrown.

Comment: Windows is updating, meanwhile i have a class with all the "Library Mfrc522Lib.cs (all in one)" (content in the link) and the upper code in the main page. It is allright?

Comment: Hi Michael, i don't get a exception thrown, program just stops work, buttons textboxes don't respond, but app dosent close

Comment: Hi Joao Pereira, I have not encountered this issue when running the code.In fact,  after ***InitIO***, there is a while loop operation, it will cause the buttons and textboxes don't respond.Please debug your application and check the point.

Answer (score 0):

I've been implementing the same reference, [RFID RC522 Raspberry PI 2 Windows IOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284498/rfid-rc522-raspberry-pi-2-windows-iot) for my RFID Attendance System and I've found that printing the detected UID into the xaml textbox freezes the program.

To fix this, you could use a task delay. This allows the textbox to update upon tag detection..

```
        var mfrc = new Mfrc522();
        await mfrc.InitIO();
        while(true)
        {
            if (mfrc.IsTagPresent())
            {
                var uid = mfrc.ReadUid().ToString();
                string uidString = uid;
                textbox1.Text = uidString;
                mfrc.HaltTag();

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the GUI Freezing, just place it through it's own thread and it'll work fine.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Thread T = new Thread(testfunc);
        T.IsBackground = true;
        T.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        T.Start();


    }
    
    public async void testfunc()
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await RFIDTask();
            
        });
    }
    
    public async Task RFIDTask()
    {
        var mfrc = new Mfrc522();
        await mfrc.InitIO();

        while (true)
        {

            while (true)
            {
                if (mfrc.IsTagPresent())
                {
                    string txt_Result = "";
                    var uid = mfrc.ReadUid();

                    foreach (byte byt in uid.FullUid)
                    {
                        txt_Result = txt_Result + byt.ToString("x2");

                    }
                    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                    {
                        tbTagId.Text = txt_Result;
                        
                    }); 
                    
                    await Task.Run(() => mfrc.HaltTag());
                    break;
                }

            }
            await Task.Delay(2000);

            mfrc.Reset();
            mfrc.HaltTag();
```